# inline reference variable, taken address across boundaries

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, inline

In a header file:

```
namespace A::B::C::D::E {
    extern const T &root_ref;
};
inline const auto &ref = A::B::C::D::E::root_ref;
```

In a cpp file of a library, which may or may not include the above header.

```
static A_class_derived_from_T obj;

namespace A::B::C::D::E {
    const T &root_ref = static_cast<T&>(obj); // Assume T is the unique, accessible base class
}
```

Are all of my understandings below correct?

1. Initialization order of "obj", "A::B::C::D::E::root_ref", and "ref" do NOT really matter because root_ref and ref are references to the base of "obj".
2. &A::B::C::D::E::root_ref and &ref should be the same and never changed (after program/lib have been loaded) value across boundaries: inside or outside the library (static library or shared library).
3. Even if obj has been changed (e.g. swapped with other variable), "A::B::C::D::E::root_ref" and "ref" are always valid and point to the base of "obj" (assume T is a unique, accessible base class).

If any of my understanding is incorrect or implementation-dependent, please help to explain. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what "do NOT really matter" means. Do not matter to whom? If there are other global objects whose initializers refer to those variables, it would start to matter.

Comment: Shared libraries do not always follow the language rules—on Windows it is typical that they do not, and you get separate global variables per DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `root_ref` was initialized before `obj`, it would be fine since you are allowed to cast to a base class even before the lifetime of the object begins (as long as `T` is not a virtual base class). But this is not a problem since `obj` is guaranteed to be initialized before `root_ref`.

However, you do run into a problem if `ref` was initialized before `root_ref` (which would happen if the cpp file included the header file). Then, `ref` would be initialized with the uninitialized `root_ref`, and you just have undefined behaviour.

You do not have this issue because `root_ref` is constant initialized, so it is guaranteed to be initialized before `ref` which is dynamically initialized. So they will refer to the same thing (the `T` base class subobject of `obj`) for the duration of the program.

References cannot be changed once they are created, so they will always refer to the `T` base class subobject of `obj`.

In summary:

1: `A::B::C::D::E::root_ref` must be initialized before `ref` (which you have)
2: What a reference refers to cannot change, and `ref` is initialized with `root_ref` so it is the same
3: See 2